# How to test child of a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I am trying to test the third child of the child component inside the root component that I am testing, so this is the situation:

```
  <Modal>
    <FlexContainer fluid>
      <FlexRow>
        <FlexColumn>
          <MainButton
            mini
            disabled={disableButtons}
          >
          </MainButton>
        </FlexColumn>
        <FlexColumn>
          <Button
            mini
            htmlType="button"
            onClick={this.addNewPeriod}
            disabled={disableButtons}
          >
          </Button>
        </FlexColumn>
      </FlexRow>
    </FlexContainer>
  </Modal>
```

I would like to test the `MainButton` and `Button` component if they are `disabled` when the `disableButtons` is `true`. I have tried to do that with the `dive` method, like this:

```
const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<Modal
      disableButtons
    />);

    const flexContainer = wrapper.find(FlexContainer);
    const flexRow = flexContainer.dive().find(FlexRow);
    const flexColumn = flexRow.dive().find(FlexColumn);
    const button= flexColumn.dive().find(Hovedknapp);

    expect(button.prop('disabled')).is.equal(true);
```

But, I get an error:

> Error: Method “dive” is only meant to be run on a single node. 2 found
>   instead.

How can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const flexColumn = flexRow.dive().find(FlexColumn).first();
```

or, if you prefer to test button in last `<FlexColumn>`

```
const flexColumn = flexRow.dive().find(FlexColumn).last();
```